# Can an API run for other users on a range of cells that is protected?

Tags: google-apps-script

We have this script.

```
function onEdit(e) {
        if(e.value != "TRUE" ) return;
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart+2).setValue(new Date());
}
```

but in the cell that the date and time is supposed to be displayed, it doesn't work for other users if the cell is protected. Is there a way to have this script function even when the cell is protected?
Regards

Juan

Comment: If the cell is protected from the user then they cannot edit it with or without the script

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there are no ways around this, a protected cell is doing its job of preventing any source from editing it.